# Do not want to see disabled products when creating an order from admin end

Tags: orders, admin

When you click on a customer in "manage customers" and then "create order", my client does not want to see the disabled products come up in the list for products to add to order. Any idea how I would go about changing this? Or at least some file location hints, lol.

I'm editing the following per below advice.

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection
            ->setStore($this->getStore())
            ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array_keys(
                Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')->asArray()
            ))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('gift_message_available');
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($collection);

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

As you can see I added `->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);` but am getting following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in
>   /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php
>   on line 109

Comment: Don't edit the core. If you must, copy the file and the full path into app/code/local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you are looking for is: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid`

Override the `_prepareCollection()` and add a filter to the `$collection` like so:

`$collection->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)`

This should filter all disabled products and only show enabled ones. Tested with CE 1.7

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get an error. See above. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Oh wait, im such a dummy! it has to go after Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status'). Works now! THank you!!!